# Use of constructor reference where constructor has a non-empty parameter list

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

Given..

```
List<Foo> copy(List<Foo> foos) {
    return foos
            .stream()
            .map(foo -> new Foo(foo))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 reports that `new Foo(foo)` "can be replaced with method reference".

I'm aware of the `Foo::new` syntax for the no-arg constructor, but don't see how I could pass `foo` in as an argument. I'm surely missing something here.

Comment: always start with the functional interface.  `map()` takes a `Function` which takes one parameter and returns a value.  When assigning a constructor reference to a `Function`, the return value is obviously the type being constructed, but since `Function` takes one parameter, so must the constructor.  If the functional type had been a `BiFunction`, it would have looked for a constructor with 2 parameters.  If the functional type had been a `Supplier`, which takes no parameters, it would have called a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm aware of the `Foo::new` syntax for the no-arg constructor

That's not what `Foo::new` does. [This expression will expand to what is needed in the context it's used.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

In this case

```
List<Foo> copy(List<Foo> foos) {
    return foos.stream().map(Foo::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

would look for a constructor that needed a `Foo` argument.

Comment: A-ha, very helpful! Thanks for setting that straight Pillar.

Comment: @Pillar Well explained

Comment: More specifically, it will use the _target type_ of the method ref as input to overload selection to find the right constructor.